# Task definitions AWS Fargate

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Let us say I am defining a task definition in AWS Fargate, this task definition would be used to start up tasks that involve a multi-container application regarding 2 web servers. How many task definitions would I need, how many tasks would I pay for and how many services are create?

I have read a lot of documentation, but it does not click for me. Is there anyone who can explain the correlation between: task definitions, task/s, Docker containers, services and ECS Fargate clusters?

Answer (score 3):

A task definition is a specification. You use it to define one or more containers (with image URIs) that you want to run together, along with other details such as environment variables, CPU/memory requirements, etc.  The task definition doesn't actually run anything, its a description of how things will be set up when something does run.

A task is an actual thing that is running. ECS uses the task definition to run the task; it downloads the container images, configures the runtime environment based on other details in the task definition.  You can run one or many tasks for any given task definition.  Each running task is a  set of one or more running containers - the containers in a task all run on the same instance.

A service in ECS is a way to run N tasks all using the same task definition, and keep those N tasks running if they happen to shut down unexpectedly.  Those N tasks can run on different instances in EC2 (although some may run on the same instance depending on the placement strategy used for the service); on Fargate, there are no instances and the tasks "just run", so you don't have to think about placement strategies. You can also use services to connect those tasks to a load balancer, so that requests from a client inside or outside of AWS can be routed evenly cross all N tasks.  You can update the task definition used by a service, which will then trigger a rolling update (starting up and shutting down running tasks) so that all running tasks will be using the new version of the task definition after the deployment completes. This is used, for example, when you create a new container image and want your service to be updated to use the latest version.

A service is scoped to a cluster.  A cluster is really just a name. Different clusters can have different IAM policies and roles, so that you can restrict who can create services in different clusters using IAM.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up, think it makes more sense to me now. I was confused about the task definition - task correlation. As I see now you can have multiple containers defined within a task definition, the only problem is using up the defined cpu and memory. Could you tell me in which cases having a lot of containers in 1 task definition would be bad, I know there is a limit to 10 containers per definition. Could you not just define "double" cpu/memory in case you needed 2 services being run using the same definition?

Comment: You typically would not run the same container image multiple times in the same task.  One reason for this is that it limits the flexibility you have to scale.  Another is that if you are using a load balancer, any given LB target group can only connect to one container in your task.  The use case for multiple containers in a task isn't to scale your service; it's to have sidecars like proxies or log/metrics containers running alongside your application container.

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. I had one doubt, if I initiate 5 tasks from a task definition, would that mean that there are 5 EC2 instances assigned to that service or is there some other configuration which defines the exact number of EC2 instances running behind a service?